# Android: How to determine if an app came from unknown source?

Tags: android

Given an application's package id, how can I tell if it came from an unknown source (i.e. user had to enable "allow untrusted source" before installing the APK)?

Comment: You can't from a package name. Maybe from something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android: How to determine if an app came from unknown source?

I think there is no way how to determine whether .apk file comes from unknown source or not. Android API cannot provide solution to reach your goal.

All what are able to do is to determine wheter application is system or not:

```
if ((info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
   // its system application
}
else {
   // its non-system application

   // here you can assume that application can be from unknown source
}
```

### Update:

There exists one possible solution but i think **it's not very efficient and reliable**. Idea is to make classic **HTTPGet** request on Google Play, for example:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.foo
```

And then check what it returns. If returned head contains someting like this:

```
<title>Not Found</title>
```

Here you can assume that application is from unknown source but **this way is not correct and reliable** because:

- You don't have access to network
- Request can return something else or in different format (this you
  can't assume)
- It consumes bytes (can be problem for mobile data for example)

Pseudo-code of request can looks like this:

```
String url = Const.MARKET + packageName;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = null;
...
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity content = response.getEntity();

String content = EntityUtils.toString(content);
if (content != null && content.contains("<title>Not Found</title>")) {
   // application is from unknown source
}
```

**Note:** Application package you are able to retrieve from PackageManager.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to make that determination (that I am aware of at least).  The distinction for this setting is that the .APK was downloaded from Google Play (trusted) or installed via some other application or downloaded from the web (untrusted).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it depends on wheter the creator of the app have signed with an google play developer key the APK or not. You can not retrieve that from the package name.